# Is HBase really a columnar database?

Tags: hbase, bigdata

I was reading about HBase and a common description for it was a "columnar database". What does this actually mean? Is HBase structured in an opposite way compared to a traditional RDBMS?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HBase isn't really a columnar database; that is a misnomer. HBase stores data in rows based on the primary key of each record. The reason why it is called "column-oriented" is that it is HBase columns are structured in column families, to be contrasted with a traditional databases. HBase tries to store records together internally in the same HFile (where HBase data is stored in Hadoop), which is why it is called "column-oriented"

If you would like to read more about true column oriented databases, here is link you might find useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column-oriented_DBMS